# With two external displays in Mountain Lion how do I specify where the content of the Desktop is shown?

Tags: macos, display, desktop

I have connected two external displays to a Macbook and have deselected 'Mirror Displays'. The lid of the Macbook is closed, therefore I am using just the larger screens. The contents of my desktop are currently only shown on screen 2.

However, I would like to tell the OS to not show the contents of the Desktop on screen 2, but on screen 1. How can I achieve that?

Sorry, if this is a duplicate, I couldn't find any question about the desktop contents.

Comment: this article might help ypu http://www.macworld.com/article/2042936/hands-on-with-os-x-mavericks-multiple-display-support.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience for Mountain Lion, determining which display is the *primary* display is usually achieved by dragging the white Menu Bar (circled in screenshot below) onto the graphic of another display, thus setting the other display as the *primary monitor*.

[image: Screenshot of my iMac's display preference pane.]

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I have tried to drag the entire blue box but didn't know that you could also drag the white one.